# Python CSV remove new lines denoted by &#x0D

Tags: python

I have a BCP file that contains lots of  carriage return symbols. They are not meant to be there and I have no control over the original output so am left with trying to parse the file to remove them.

A sample of the data looks like....

```
"test1","apples","this is &#x0D;
some sample","3877"
"test66","bananas","this represents more &#x0D;
wrong data","378"
```

I am trying to send up with...

```
"test1","apples","this is some sample","3877"
"test66","bananas","this represents more wrong data","378"
```

Is there a simple way to do this prefereably using python CSV?

Comment: Is there a reason you need Python CSV?  You can just 1) read the file,  2) perform a string replacement on the file contents as in `file_contents.replace('&#x0D;\n', '')`, 3) write the new_contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
import re

with open("old.csv") as f, open("new.csv", "w") as w:
  for line in f:
    line = re.sub(r"&#x0D;\s*", "", line)
    w.write(line)
```

---

```
"test1","apples","this is some sample","3877"
"test66","bananas","this represents more wrong data","378"
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/68dc4f03f3)